# MemoryStream is not writing everything expected to the file

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream, memorystream

My problem is to write some data about passangers to the `MemoryStream` and then copy it to the file. I need to realize it in two different methods. In methods I need to use `Stream`, then in `Main` function I use `MemoryStream`. So I wrote this code:

```
    public static void WriteToStream(Stream stream)
    {
        Random rnd = new();
        StreamWriter sw = new(stream);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(i);
            sw.WriteLine($"Passanger{i}");
            sw.WriteLine(rnd.Next(0, 2) == 1);
        }
    }

    public static void CopyFromStream(Stream stream, string filename)
    {
        using var fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        stream.CopyTo(fs);
    }
```

Main function:

```
MemoryStream ms = new();

StreamService.WriteToStream(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamService.CopyFromStream(ms, "database.dat");
```

But when I open the file, I see that there is not all the passangers. I need to write 100 passangers (according to the cycle on the first method) but there is only 87 passangers. File looks like this:

```
//some other passangers from 0 to 82, everything is fine with them
83
Passanger83
False
84
Passanger84
False
85
Passanger85
True
86
Passanger86
False
87
Passanger87
T
```

As you see at the end of the file the `True` statement is broken and there is not enough passangers in this file. Can somebody tell me what is the problem?

P.S. I posted this code today already in another question but now I fixed previous problem. Now I have another problem with it so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Try adding `sw.Flush();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set `StreamWriter.AutoFlush` property to `true` in your `WriteToStream` method:

```
StreamWriter sw = new(stream) { AutoFlush = true };
```

And add manual deletion of your file if it exists for proper overwrite:

```
public static void CopyFromStream(Stream stream, string filename)
{
    if (File.Exists(filename))
        File.Delete(filename);

     using var fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
     stream.CopyTo(fs);
}
```

Tested and works well on many iterations.

Comment: So it was enough to add sw.Flush() at the end of first method but your method is working as well. Thanks a lot!